# Enable Stereo-Mix or "listen in function" of Audio input device and set the corresponding output device

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to programaticly enable the Windows listen-in function of an audio input device and set the corresponding output device. I did ask chatgpt with little success as it told me to set the value of the PKEY_AudioEndpoint_Enable_Stereo_Mix property, which doesn't exist or how to set the default audio devices.
Looking forward to your help as I'm a beginner in C++.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does not have API to directly control or query the "listen to this device" checkbox or device selection.

[Access to the "Listen to this device" setting (microsoft.com)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/f243f5e2-c2ac-4cec-8f57-0825cab48af5/access-to-the-quotlisten-to-this-devicequot-setting?forum=windowspro-audiodevelopment)

But there are two ways to achieve the requirements:

1. **Microsoft High Quality Voice Capture DMO**：
   The voice capture DMO is a DirectX Media Object that provides a complete solution of high-quality audio capture on personal computers. It takes microphone (and speaker if AEC is enabled) input signals and produced output signals. Obtaining outputs, Setting DMO input and output formats by Voice Capture DMO interfaces.
   [image]

For more details, you can download the [readme .rtf](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/27ffb0811ca761741502feaefdb591aebf592193/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/audio/aecmicarray)  and the [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/27ffb0811ca761741502feaefdb591aebf592193/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/audio/aecmicarray) about Microsoft High Quality Voice Capture DMO.

2. **Implement it with the AutoIt scripting tool**：
   This [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/617669/quicker-way-to-swap-microphones-speakers-in-windows-7) explained how to use **Set Sound Device** to switch between microphone and speaker without entering sound options and manually swapping default audio devices and default communication devices.